# Can XmlSerializer use double quotes in declaration instead of single quotes?

Tags: java, xml, opencv, android

I am using Android's XmlSerializer to generate a .xml file to be used with the OpenCV library (as a way to input parameters for SimpleBlobDetector).

The problem is that the generated XML uses single quotes/apostrophes ( ' ) in the declaration:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
```

Unfortunately, OpenCV does not read single quotation marks. It only reads XML that uses double quotes ( " ) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

---

I have tried manually changing the single quotes into double quotes and the file worked after that. However, it's not feasible for me to manually do this all the time.

If it helps, the declaration is the only part of the .xml file with any quotes at all, but OpenCV requires the declaration so I cannot simply omit it. I have tried manually editing the declaration and found that it works with just a bare-bones delcaration:

```
<?xml ?>
```

Is there a way for XmlSerializer to generate a .xml file with double quotes instead of single quotes like it is currently doing? If not, is there a way to remove the version number and encoding?

---

Here's a small snippet of my code, if it helps:

```
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
        xmlSerializer.setOutput(outputStream,"UTF-8");
        xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8",null);
        xmlSerializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output", true);


        //Begin filling in content
        xmlSerializer.startTag(null,"thresholdStep");
        xmlSerializer.text(Double.toString(thresholdStep));
        xmlSerializer.endTag(null,"thresholdStep");

        //End document
        xmlSerializer.endDocument();
        xmlSerializer.flush();

        //Close output stream
        outputStream.close();
```

Comment: Just drop the startDocument() method and write the line directly to the stream, that solves it for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to generate double quotes using DOM instead of XmlSerializer, following [this example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/).

The resulting xml file could then be read by OpenCV without any problems.